# Pass an HTML element surrounded by text as a props argument

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm passing all my arguments to my component using `defaultProps`

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    arg1: "hello"
    arg2: "word"
}
```

I am able to pass an entire link tag like so

```
   arg3: <a id="link" href="https://github.com/myLink">View my portfolio on Github.</a>
```

I would like only the word GitHub to be the hyperlink though. So the argument would look more like this:

```
"View my portfolio on" <a id="link" href="https://github.com/myLink">Github.</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass one HTML element that encapsulates everything you want displayed.

```
<span>View my portfolio on <a id="link" href="https://github.com/myLink">Github.</a></span>
```